Connection lost, never recovers after adding interface to bridge
My connection is lost when I add an interface to a bridge. Here I want to add eno3 to bridge kvbr0:
sudo ip link add name kvbr0 type bridge
sudo ip addr del 10.120.224.70/23 dev eno3
sudo ip addr add 10.120.224.70/23 brd + dev kvbr0 
sudo ip link set eno3 master br0
sudo ip link set kvbr0 up

10.120.224.70 is the IP address of eno3. After running the above, I can no longer ssh into this address.
This is what I see for the interfaces:
kvbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1316
        inet 10.120.224.70  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 10.120.225.255
        ether xxxxxx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 12920  bytes 791021 (772.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5  bytes 214 (214.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1316
        ether xxxxxx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 29895  bytes 2308765 (2.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 41  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1431  bytes 802466 (783.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0x96200000-962fffff

kvbr0 has the previous IP settings from eno3.
The server is running Rocky9 with kernel 6.1.
I tried the above commands on a VM machine running Ubuntu, and I can ssh into the IP address. Is there anything I should be aware of on the server that would prevent network connectivity after running those commands?
The server has an Intel I350 NIC. The product brief says the adapter is "bridgeless." Could this be causing the problem I'm seeing?


Is this a VM? 2) Does the new bridge have the same MAC address as the original Ethernet interface?



No. 2) Yes. I hid the MAC in my question.


There wasn't a default route:
ip route add default via 10.120.225.1 dev kvbr0

I realized this was the issue when I observed I could ping the server from a machine on the local network but not from an outside machine.
